# Solve the ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away without change the max_allowed_packet

Tags: mysql, sql, ssh, import, session-timeout

I'm trying to import a SQL database file which is 750MB by using ssh into my new database.
The `Sql1043724_1.sql` is already on the server.

When I run this command:

```
mysql -u u77066539X -p u770665391_db < Sql1043XX_1.sql
```

I get:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 5262: MySQL server has gone away
```

Unfortunately, in the /etc/my.cnf file I have `max_allowed_packet=16M` and I cannot change it because I don't have a root account. I asked to my hosting provider and they cannot change the value for me.

Is there any other procedure that I can use to solve my problem and import my old database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The maximum packet size relates to how long a line of SQL can be in the `.sql` file.  The size of the file itself does not matter.

I have found success with overcoming this problem but I configured both the server and use a command line to use a large packet size.  Try this:

```
mysql -u u77066539X -p --max_allowed_packet=1073741824 u770665391_db < Sql1043XX_1.sql
```

Comment: I get always the same error: ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 5262: MySQL server has gone away

Should I split the database somehow and then upload each part separately?

Comment: The problem will be that some of the SQL statements in the `.sql` file are too large.  You could load small tables separately.  You could try to find the long SQL lines, and do something, like take them out of the import.  These are not full solutions because you would then be missing that data.